# Creating a structured Jenkins Failing Test Report

Tags: jenkins, junit, automation, reporting

The situation right now:

Every Monday morning I manually check Jenkins jobs jUnit results that ran over the weekend, using Project Health plugin I can filter on the timeboxed runs. I then copy paste this table into Excel and go over each test case's output log to see what failed and note down the failure cause. Every weekend has another tab in Excel. All this makes tracability a nightmare and causes time consuming manual labor.

What I am looking for (and hoping that already exists to some degree):

A database that stores all failed tests for all jobs I specify. It parses the output log of a failed test case and based on some regex applies a 'tag' e.g. 'Audio' if a test regarding audio is failing. Since everything is in a database I could make or use a frontend that can apply filters at will.

For example, if I want to see all tests regarding audio failing over the weekend (over multiple jobs and multiple runs) I could run a query that returns all entries with the Audio tag.

I'm OK with manually tagging failed tests and the cause, as well as writing my own frontend, is there a way (Jenkins API perhaps?) to grab the failed tests (jUnit format and Jenkins plugin) and create such a system myself if it does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good question. Unfortunately, it is very difficult in Jenkins to get such "meta statistics" that spans several jobs. There is no existing solution for that.

Basically, I see two options for getting what you want:

1. **Post-processing Jenkins-internal data** to get the statistics that you need.
2. **Feeding a database on-the-fly** with build execution data.

The **first option** basically means automating the tasks that you do manually right now.

- you can use external scripting (Python, Perl,...) to process Jenkins-internal data (via REST or CLI APIs, or directly reading on-disk data)
- or you run Groovy scripts internally (which will be faster and more powerful)

It's the most direct way to go. However, depending on the statistics that you need and depending on your requirements regarding data persistance , you may want to go for...

The **second option**: more flexible and completely decoupled from Jenkins' internal data storage. You could implement it by

- introducing a Groovy post-build step for all your jobs
- that script parses job results and puts data of interest in a custom, external database

Statistics you'd get from querying that database.

**Typically**, you'd start with the first option. Once requirements grow, you'd slowly migrate to the second one (e.g., by collecting internal data via explicit post-processing scripts, putting that into a database, and then running queries on it). You'll want to cut this migration phase as short as possible, as it eventually requires the effort of implementing *both* options.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [couchdb-statistics](https://plugins.jenkins.io/couchdb-statistics). It is far from a perfect fit, but at least seems to do partially what you want to achieve.